# How do you set inline breakpoints in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

There's no longer a context menu option to set a breakpoint "in-line".
Example:

```
if (someBoolean) return CallToMyMethod();
```

With previous versions of VS I could simply right click "CallToMyMethod" and set a breakpoint there. There doesn't seem to be a way of doing this anymore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Just highlight the method name or the part where you need the breakpoint and then press F9.

Comment: thanks! I'm still really disappointed that the context menu option has been taken away. That was one bit of functionality of using breakpoints I use(d) the most. :(